# Gradient of Perspective function

Tags: derivatives, convex-optimization, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

I was reading the convex optimization book from Prof Boyd and Prof Vandenberghe and In chapter 3, I had a doubt regarding the perspective function.

In page 89, the perspective function of a function f is defined as :

$g(x,t)=tf(x/t)$

assuming
$f: R^{n}→R$
so that
$g:R^{n+1}→R$
and also
$x,t∈ dom(f),t>0$

I was wondering what would be the gradient of $g(x,t)$ in terms of $t$ and $f(x/t)$. Please, can someone help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gradient of $g$ follows from chain rule:

$$\nabla_{n+1} g(x,t) = \left( \nabla_n f\left(\frac{x}{t}\right),\: f\left(\frac{x}{t}\right) - \frac{x}{t}\cdot\nabla_n f\left(\frac{x}{t}\right) \right)$$

where the "first" term is really a list of entries of length $n$.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Oh, I'm sorry I by mistake wrote it as $f(xt)$ rather than $f(x/t)$. I guess we just have to change x*t with x/t and multiplication terms of t to division terms right?

Comment: @adithya I have fixed my answer which does exactly the same chain rule as the last one.